# How to shorten long reusable modifiers like font style, foreground styles, etc

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-text

I have a custom font modifier that I am using often, however it makes the code very long as I need to add it in multiple places.

This is the modifier:

```
.font(.custom("Bebas Neue", size: 24)).foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("lb"), Color("rb")]),startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
```

How can I shorten this so I can import it ideally with a single word or so?

Comment: Look into ViewModifiers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom view modifier.

#### Custom Modifier

```
struct TextModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    let gradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("lb"), Color("rb")]),startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(.custom("Bebas Neue", size: 24)).foregroundStyle(gradient)
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
Text("How are you today? ☀️")
    .modifier(TextModifier())
```

#### Extra (optional)

If you want an easier way to use the modifer you can create an extension on View, like so:

```
extension View {
    func textStyle() -> some View {
        modifier(TextModifier())
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
Text("How are you today? ☀️")
    .textStyle()
```

---

More about [ViewModifiers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewmodifier) and [Extensions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/extensions/)

Hope this helps :)